# HHVM 3.0.1 with Symfony 1.4 session not being set

Tags: php, nginx, centos, symfony-1.4, hhvm

I've got HHVM 3.0.1 running with FASTCGI and Nginx with Symfony1.4

But I'm getting below error from HHVM error log:

```
\nNotice: Undefined index: 10 in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php on line 853
\nNotice: Undefined index: 10 in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php on line 853
\nNotice: Undefined index: 10 in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php on line 853
\nNotice: Undefined index: 10 in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php on line 853
\nNotice: Undefined index: 10 in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php on line 853
\nNotice: Undefined index: 10 in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/routing/sfRoute.class.php on line 853
\nFatal error: Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: ) in /vagrant/SecureAccountsServices/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/storage/sfDatabaseSessionStorage.class.php on line 73
```

Strange that below is already set in php.ini and is used as config for HHVM also both Nginx and HHVM daemon has been restarted

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /tmp
```

The only way to get any page output is to have `ini_set(‘session.save_handler’, ‘files’);` `before session_start();` for each of the storage classes which is strange…

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: The error appears in the `sfDatabaseSessionStorage` class so it looks like you are trying to use database as your session storage. Check your `factories.yml` for the storage settings, and the database if everything is ok there.